# Filter shared inbox mail by user name which is stored in a user-defined field

Tags: vba, outlook

We are using a shared inbox. Each mail is assigned to a person. The assignment is done in a user-defined field "Bearbeiter" containing the name of the person.

I want to define a view, in which the person only sees mails he is assigned. I can assign a DASL / sql-filter with the following.

**The filter is formatted like a hyperlink but this is the filter condition.**
"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Bearbeiter" LIKE '%max%'

I need 'max' to be replaced by the first name of the user, something like

```
instr("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/Bearbeiter";username) <> 0
```

I could use VBA like in https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/25904435/DASL-filter-in-Outlook-2003-Username.html, but that would mean I had to call the function every time, which I do not want.

Comment: Please post your code not link

Comment: in a DASL-filter there is no code, you can only enter the filter-condition (I have inserted that, it looks like a link but it is not! - i removed the hyperlink-format). The code in the link is an other solution for the same problem, but it has the hegative impacts mentioned above. I just wanted to make clear, that this is NOT what i want.